# Align multiline RHS

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath, align

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    L_W&=\frac{L}{W}    & \text{words per line}&=\frac{\text{bytes per line}}{\text{bytes per word}} \\
    s&=\frac{l}{s}      & \text{number of sets}&=\frac{\text{number of lines}}{\text{associativity}} \\
    a_{off}&=ld_2(w)    & \text{address offset bits}&=ld_2(\text{words per line}) \\
    a_{s}&=ld_2(s)      & \text{address set bits}&=ld_2(\text{number of sets}) \\
    t&=a_b-a_s-a_{off}  & \text{address tag bit}&=\begin{aligned}
     &\text{address bits} \\
        -&\text{address set bits}\\
        -&\text{address offset bits}
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The output, with what I would like to change highlighted is this:

[image: mwe plus highlight]

1. I would like to move the RHS of the second equation in row (5), so that address bits aligns with `=` and the equation number. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44451/19326 comes close  but the equation number is centered. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105639/19326 comes close as well but here I can't see how to handle the equation number and alignment of the formulas in the first column). Note that I want to align by the variable name and not by the sign. especially note the gap left between the equals sign and the first variable, so that the signs of the rows below wont vertically overlap with the equals sign)
2. I would like to add equal spacing, I tried: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9151/19326 (by adding `\savebox\strutbox{$\vphantom{\frac{\text{bytes per line}}{\text{bytes per wordi}}\frac{L}{W}}$}`) but this still seams to give different spacing. (see between 3/4 with the addition) (currently not included since I am afraid that this will extend the entire enviornment downwards.

Comment: Why not use `alignat` and specify all the alignment points?  For (2), add `[.xcm]` to the end of (3).  Play around with x until you are satisfied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spacing between rows can be adjusted with `\vphantom`; the `aligned` can be treated with `[t]` so the first line is level with `=`. However, centering the equation number is not something I would even try.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\vphtextfr}{\vphantom{\frac{\text{by}}{\text{ty}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
L_W&=\frac{L}{W} & 
  \text{words per line}&=\frac{\text{bytes per line}}{\text{bytes per word}} \\
s&=\frac{l}{s} &
  \text{number of sets}&=\frac{\text{number of lines}}{\text{associativity}} \\
a_\textup{off}&=\mathit{ld}_2(w) &
  \text{address offset bits}&=\mathit{ld}_2(\text{words per line})\vphtextfr \\
a_{s}&=\mathit{ld}_2(s) &
  \text{address set bits}&=\mathit{ld}_2(\text{number of sets})\vphtextfr \\
t&=a_b-a_s-a_\textup{off} &
  \text{address tag bit}\vphtextfr&=
    \begin{aligned}[t]
     &\text{address bits} \\
    -&\text{address set bits}\\
    -&\text{address offset bits}
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Note the usage of `\textup{off}`: it's not the product of three quantities, but a word. Also use `\mathit{ld}` for a multiletter identifier.

[image]

Comment: In your example adding `vphantom` works nicely, however I was amazed by the simplicity of setting up a savebox `strutbox`. The biggest issue with it was that It did not work correctly when I tried. Do you have any idea why? (I have more equations and would love the automation achieved by the linked awnser)

Comment: @ted You should have used `\dfrac`, not `\frac`.

Comment: Also where do you get `textup` from (I cant find it in the [amsmath doc](http://funnyshare.org/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf), find returns no results), and what is the difference to `text`. For those who do not know about `displaystyle`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71033/19326. It basically fixes the fact that in inline math mode the fraction is set in a smaller size than in the `align` enviornment. Therefore it suffices to use `\dfrac` in the `\savebox\strutbox`

Comment: One last thing, i think it should be `\operatorname` for `ld_2` since `ld_2` refers to `ld` to logaritmus dualis (log to base 2) after researching typesetting math a bit more. While you as a prof will now somebody else like me might come across this.

Comment: @ted If it's an operator like `\log`, then it should be upright and `\operatorname{ld}` is good. You can also do `\DeclareMathOperator{\ld}{ld}` in the preamble and use `\ld_2` in the document.