# Make limit in inline mode same position as display mode

Tags: amsmath

If I use:

```
$$\lim_{x\to3}f(x)$$
```

Then the x to 3 is placed below the limit. But if I write:

Given `$f(x)=x^2$`, evaluate `$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$`, ...

Then the limit is put below right of the limit symbol. How can I place the x to 3 below the limit symbol in inline mode?

Answer (score 13):

The “correct” way is to type

```
$\lim\limits_{x\to 3} f(x)$
```

because `\displaystyle` would change many other aspects of math typesetting that are good in displays but not in line. See [displaystyle, dfrac, dcases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71028/displaystyle-dfrac-dcases) for examples.

The command `\limits` can go after any math operator taking limits, such as `\sum` and `\max`.

Avoid doing this, because it spoils the spacing between lines, leaving huge white strips on your page. The formula `$\lim_{x\to 3} f(x)$` is as readable as the one with the condition underneath ‘lim’.

Also avoid `$$` in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 3):

This is easy to fix.  Just write

```
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$
```

Incidentally, using `$$...$$` for display equations is not advised.  You should use

```
\[\lim_{x\to3}f(x)\]
```

instead.